# Error: max retries exceeded:get Get "https://xyz.z2.cloudflarestorage.com/ollama/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/78/numbers/data?X-A-Algorithm=xyz&xy

Tags: ssl, timeout, max, limit, handshake

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 series and I am installing the LLM using Ollama models page and I am getting an error while installing the LLM in my terminal.

the error is :
pulling manifest
pulling 780d31d1e3e8...  82% ▕█████████████   ▏ 6.0 GB/7.4 GB  881 KB/s  25m45s
Error: max retries exceeded: Get "https://dd20bb891979d25aebc8bec07b2b3bbc.r2.cloudflarestorage.com/ollama/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/78/780d31d1e3e818fe45e5c3391892909c7b085ec19ea0f213d314a2506d91da61/data?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=66909d77mc1b787c3af801529929349a%!H(MISSING)20240305%!H(MISSING)auto%!H(MISSING)s3%!H(MISSING)aws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20240305T055445Z&X-Amz-Expires=1200&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=a1b98e9c4c77ee7a06933acb2d52be40c7ba79d54041cc4a39082e857984e052": net/http: TLS handshake timeout

firstly I had installed Ollama using : curl -fsSL https://ollama.com/install.sh | sh
in the terminal (without using virtual environment)
and then trying to install the model using : ollama run codeup:13b
in the terminal.

I had tried  ollama run codeup:13b
and expecting that the model gets installed successfully